# K2 item assigned to menu to displaying

Tags: k2

In my menu item I assigned `K2 > Item` and I choosed my item to be displayed, but it's not working. I've been working with K2 for several months and this is the first time this is happening.

For the K2 item I set 'show' in Title and Full text, but the strange thing is that the only thing being displayed is the social networks share plugin (I disabled them). Another thing is that if I set to `featured item` it will display correctly the default feaured banner.

If I assign to my menu item `K2 » Latest items from (one or more) users or categories`, it works. It just doesn't work with `K2 > Item`.

PS: Items are published and with shown proprieties.

Answer (score 1):

Solved: After many hours of several tries, I found out that FLEXIcontent plugin was causing conflicts with K2, so I had to uninstall it. Works fine after uninstall.